# Limiting the PHP DOM Parsed statements from a forum site with 'if' condition

Tags: php

I been trying to parse statements/questions from a forum site using a DOM parser. 
Its working fine, it extracts all statements in the forum. So, i tried to put a limit of extracting statements using a `if` condition. it still doesn't fix the problem.

I thought the problem in structuring the if condition, so i ran the loop separately and it worked..

the code goes as follows:

```
<?php
    $i = 1;
    $elementCount=0;
    while(true){
    require_once('dom/simple_html_dom.php'); 
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.usmleforum.com/forum/index.php?forum=1&Page='.$i);
    foreach ($html->find("tr") as $row) {
    $element = $row->find('td.FootNotes2',0);
    if ($element == null) { continue; }
    $textNode = array_filter($element->nodes, function ($n) {
    return $n->nodetype == 3;        //Text node type, like in jQuery     
});
    if (!empty($textNode)) {
    $text = current($textNode);
    echo $text."<br>"; 
    $elementCount++;
}
}
    if($elementCount==12){
           break;
    }
    $i++;
}
?>
```

So, even after adding the if condition for 12 statements it still runs for forever.

now the if condition alone:

```
<?php
    $i = 1;
    $elementCount=0;
    while(true){
    echo "harish".$i."<br>";
    $elementCount++;
    if($elementCount==12){
           break;
}
    $i++;
}
?>
```

It works fine, prints only 12 given statement.

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: if is a condition check not a loop

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you are incrementing the $elementCount correctly but since I cannot see the output of your code I'm not sure. 
I would move the break statement before the $elementCount++ and also echo the $elementCount to figure out what's really going on.

The resulting code would be like this:

```
<?php
$i = 1;
$elementCount=0;
while(true){
    require_once('dom/simple_html_dom.php'); 
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.usmleforum.com/forum/index.php?forum=1&Page='.$i);
    foreach ($html->find("tr") as $row) {
        $element = $row->find('td.FootNotes2',0);
        if ($element == null) { continue; }
        $textNode = array_filter($element->nodes, function ($n) {
        return $n->nodetype == 3;        //Text node type, like in jQuery     
    });
    if (!empty($textNode)) {
        $text = current($textNode);
        echo $text."<br>"; 
        echo $elementCount;
         if($elementCount===12){
               break;
        }
        $elementCount++;
    }
}

$i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: I took out the `echo $elementCount;` from your answer and tried it, yet it still prints all the statements..

Comment: Ok, I'm looking at your code more closely and I see that you have two loops, the **while** and the **foreach** . So the while is always true and runs all the time until the $elementCount reaches 12 and then again. Try running your code without the **while** loop. Sorry I missed this in my answer.

Comment: There is an optional numerical argument you can use with `break` that you can use to specify which loop level you want to exit. The default value is 1, which refers to the `foreach` loop. By using `break 2` you can leave the `while` loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should better structure your code. So you would see that you increment the elementCount inside the foreach.

As you are checking outside of the foreach for the exact elementCount it can happen, that your counter rises above 12 elements and now will run forever.

You could just change the loop to

```
while($elementCount < 12) {...}
```

So you are checking if you have less than 12 and not exactly 12 or to:

```
if ($elementCount >= 12) {...}
```